# could not build Objective-C module 'SwiftDate'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I 'm using framework "SwiftDate" in my workspace (i tried to use it like a pod but that failed) and the problem is always the same -" could not build Objective-C module 'SwiftDate'"How to deal with it?
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should try updating the pod using `pod update SwiftDate` and then running `pod install` to regenerate the pod

Comment: Can't update it cause the new version is not compatible with Swift 2.3

Comment: Then you have to convert the current pod's syntax to Swift 2.3 on your own